# what is the right inotify event mask configuration for monitoring writes to a file?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, inotify

I am trying to use inotify to monitor a file for any reads or writes.

typical use case would be user runs one of the following commands and I get the appropriate notification.

**`echo "xyz" > /tmp/the_file`** # This should give me a write notification

OR

**`cat /tmp/the_file`** # This should give me an access notification.

I have tried the following masks :

- `mask = (IN_MODIFY|IN_ACCESS);`  //gets correct notification for reads , for writes i get 2 notifications
- `mask = (IN_CLOSE_WRITE|IN_ACCESS);`  // gets correct notification for reads , no notification for writes.

what would be the right mask value to get a single notification for every read and write ?

I am using the test application from this blog as reference :
[How to Use inotify API in C Language](https://linuxhint.com/inotify_api_c_language/)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/inotify.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

#define MAX_EVENTS 1024
#define LEN_NAME 256
#define EVENT_SIZE  (sizeof (struct inotify_event))
#define BUF_LEN     (MAX_EVENTS * (EVENT_SIZE + LEN_NAME))

int fd,wd;
void sig_handler(int sig){
  inotify_rm_watch(fd, wd);
  close(fd);
  exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  char *path_to_be_watched;
  int i=0,length;
  char buffer[BUF_LEN];
  struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *) &buffer[i];

  path_to_be_watched = argv[1];
  signal(SIGINT,sig_handler);
  fd = inotify_init();
  fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
  wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, path_to_be_watched, IN_MODIFY | IN_ACCESS);

  if(wd==-1){
    printf("Could not watch : %s\n", path_to_be_watched);
  } else {
    printf("Watching : %s\n", path_to_be_watched);
  }

  while(1){
    i=0;
    length = read(fd,buffer,BUF_LEN);

    while(i<length){
      event = (struct inotify_event *) &buffer[i];

      if(event->len){
        if ( event->mask & IN_MODIFY ) {
          printf( "The file %s was modified.\n", event->name );
          /* This gets printed twice when I run 'echo "123" > /tmp/this_file' */
        }
        else if ( event->mask & IN_ACCESS ) {
          printf( "The file %s was accessed.\n", event->name );
        }
      }
      i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
    }
  }

  return(0);
}
```

Snippet of strace for `echo "hello" > ./a.txt`

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "./a.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
fcntl64(1, F_GETFD)                     = 0
fcntl64(1, F_DUPFD, 10)                 = 10
fcntl64(1, F_GETFD)                     = 0
fcntl64(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)        = 0
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
close(3)                                = 0
write(1, "hello\n", 6)                  = 6
dup2(10, 1)                             = 1
fcntl64(10, F_GETFD)                    = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
close(10)                               = 0
```

Comment: `gets correct notification for reads , for writes i get 2 notifications` So looks like it works, so use it. Why not use it if it works?

Comment: @KamilCuk 
I need one event for each write to the file, 
ie. one event every time  i run  ```echo "xyz" > /tmp/the_file```
I can try ignoring the next event whenever i get the first notification for IN_MODIFY, however i dont know if this is the right way to proceed.

It would help if someone could shed some light on why there are 2 events getting generated.

Comment: `one event for each write to the file` Well, how do you know that `echo "xyz" > /tmp/the_file` does not make two `write()` calls? I guess it does `write("xyz", ...)` and then `write('\n', ...)`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried running strace on a bash script to try and see if i can decipher the file IO that occur.

Im still new to this and dont quite get what ```fcntl146()``` and ```dup2()``` do.

however it looks like there is a single ```write()``` happening over here am i wrong ?


I have added the output of strace above as an edit.

Comment: Also I had initially said that when i use 
```mask = (IN_MODIFY|IN_ACCESS);``` " for writes i get 2 notifications"

however If I run ```echo "xyz" > ./the_file```  say 100 times 
the above statement holds true around 93+ times , ie it varies every run.

Comment: Strangely enough I don't get any output at all if I compile and run your example above.  Which distro & version are you doing this on?

Comment: its a custom Linux build for arm, let me try and reproduce on my ubuntu system

Comment: @tink I am able to reproduce this behavior on my ubuntu x86 laptop
1). you can only watch a folder path; 2). The file you want to watch should exist and contain some data before you run the application; 3) mkdir /tmp/test; echo 1 > /tmp/test/a.txt; ./a.out /tmp/test